# How do I prove that $\dfrac{1}{4} \geq r-r^2$ for $r$ a real number between $0<r<1$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I can obviously look at the graph or take the derivative of the function, but I need a more direct and logic based proof. I'm basically just having trouble showing that the value of $(r-r^2)$ decreases for r greater than or less than $1/2$ when $r$  $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**

You want to show this:

$$-r^2+r \le \frac{1}{4}.$$

This is equivalent to showing that

$$0 \le r^2 - r + \frac{1}{4}.$$

Can this be factored? What do you know about the resulting quantity? Keep signs in mind..

Comment: @Mason Maybe things get clearer if you multiply both sides by $4$.

Comment: simplifying it into a quadratic I could factor made it a lot easier, I should've thought of that. Thanks for the help cameron.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You could use AM/GM on the two real numbers $r,1-r$. So:

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{r+(1-r)}{2} \geq \sqrt{r(1-r)}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is because the maximum or minimum of a quadratic function with real roots is obtained at the mean of the roots.

Here, $r(1-r)$ has roots $0$ and $1$, and it has a *maximum* since the coefficient of $r^2$ is negative, obtained at $\frac 14$. Thus by definition of a maximum:
$$\frac12\Bigl(1-\frac12\Bigr)=\frac14\ge r(1-r)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
r^2-r+\frac{1}{4}=\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq 0
$$